# "Cannot overload functions by return type alone" error

Tags: c++

I keep getting a "cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone" when it comes to my function 
**string processOpen(char name)**
and I'm not sure why. I've cut the program to just it's basic shell and still no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The actual visual studio error during compile says
"missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


char openCommand();
string processOpen(char entryReturn);
bool logIn(string name);
bool addNewMember(string name);
void processQuit();


//Global Variables
string memberlist = "memberlist.txt";                                 
string checkedOutList = "checkedoutbooks.txt";

using namespace std;
int main() {

char entryReturn = ' ';                                         
string name;                                                    

while (entryReturn != 'q') {

    entryReturn = openCommand();
    name = processOpen(entryReturn);
}

return 0;
 }
```

the function looks like

```
string processOpen(char entryReturn) {

bool allReadyThere = false;                                     
string name = " ";

//This will process the <log in> selection
if (entryReturn == 'a')
{
    cout << "Enter your first and last name" << endl;

    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, name);

    allReadyThere = logIn(name);

    if (allReadyThere == false)
    {
        cout << "You need to register 
       as you don't have an account"        <<        endl;
    }
 }

//This will process the <register> selection
else if (entryReturn == 'b')
{
    cout << "Enter your first and last name" << endl;

    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, name);

    allReadyThere = addNewMember(name);

    if (allReadyThere == true) {
        cout << "you already have an account" << endl;
    }
}

else if (entryReturn == 'q') {

    processQuit();
}

else
{
    cout << "This is a non working command";
}

return name;
}
```

be kind with code I'm still a little new. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format your code correctly (indent it, remove all the excess vertical whitespace, fix the broken strings), and then post the *exact* error message.

Comment: okay, just give me second. Sorry

Comment: Please point us to the offending line the compiler gives.

Comment: @Paul On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: The second function declaration (line 7 on this screen???) . Its the  String processOpen(char entryReturn).

Comment: Well I can't reproduce this error with what you've given us. https://ideone.com/q0mW5q Perhaps there is another function named processOpen that only differs in what it returns from the function you've given us. At any rate, this is not enough for anyone to help here

Comment: I think i might have solved it but it it's not anything I assumed would matter,  I moved my "using namespace std" to before my function declarations and now it seems to work. Strange

Answer (score 4):

At the line:

```
string processOpen(char entryReturn);
```

the compiler doesn't know what `string` means. You should have written `std::string` here.

Apparently, your compiler guessed that you misspelt `int` . (Compilers are smart these days, right?).

Then, later on you wrote `using namespace std;` followed by `string processOpen(char entryReturn) {`. At that point, the compiler finds `string` inside `namespace std`,  and it sees that you have defined two functions with the same name and parameters, but one returning `int` and one returning `std::string`, which is not allowed.

This is a good example of why you should focus your attention to the first output message from the compiler (be it "error" or "warning", there's no difference really) .  After encountering an error, the compiler guesses something about what you meant and tries to keep compiling, but clearly any subsequent messages are tainted by the results of this guess, if it didn't guess right.

Once you fixed the first message, then recompile to see if the other "cascaded" messages also go away.